# How to make the target of the artillery yml file configurable / variable?

Tags: node.js, npm, load, artillery

```
config:
  target: "https://some-site.com"
```

This my current setup. the target is static. I want to make it variable, either through a command line argument or environment argument.

For Example:

```
config:
  target: "{{ target_site }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three options:

#### Option 1. `processEnvironment`

Use `$processEnvironment` to get a variable from an environment variable:

```yaml
config:
  target: "{{ $processEnvironment.TARGET_URL }}"
```

And run with `TARGET_URL=https://some-site.com artillery run scenario.yml`

---

#### Option 2. `--variables`

Define your YAML like this:

```yaml
config:
  target: "{{ targetUrl }}"
```

And then run your scenario by passing in the `targetUrl` variable:

`artillery run scenario.yml --variables '{ "targetUrl": "https://some-site.com" }'`

---

#### Option 3. `--dotenv`

Create a `.env` file with the URL:

```bash
TARGET_URL=https://some-site.com
```

Then, create your scenario as in the first option.

Finally, run your scenario with:

`artillery run scenario.yml --dotenv <path_to_dotenv_file>`